# How to reliably get block device name for EC2 instance store?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

Running CentOS on an AWS EC2 instance, I want to make a startup script that formats and mounts the NVMe instance store.  So far, every time I reboot, the EBS boot drive is `/dev/nvme0n1` and the ephemeral instance store is `/dev/nvme1n1`.  But according to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html), it sounds like this is not guaranteed.  How can I reliably get the name of the instance store block device, so I don't format the boot drive by mistake?

I tried getting instance metadata with curl, but this command returns `sda1` even though `/dev/sda1` does not exist.  Not sure what that is supposed to mean.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ami/
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but instead of polling the `ami` block device mapping, you can poll the `ephemeral0` one, which would give you the name of the device you mapped when you started your instance: `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/ephemeral0`. I don't know yet how to map `ephemeral0` to the actual `/dev/nvmeXnY` disk though.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to look into `/dev/disk/by-id/`.

E.g., the following adds the first local block device as swap (if there is one):

```
for DEVICE in /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_EC2_NVMe_Instance_Storage*; do
  if [ -e $DEVICE ]; then 
    mkswap $DEVICE; 
    swapon $DEVICE; 
    break; 
  fi;
done
```

(Tested on CentOS 8 and Ubuntu 18.04.)

I haven't found any official documentation for this, but it is adapted from code in a blog at https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/containers/optimizing-spark-performance-on-kubernetes/. There the slightly different pattern `/dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_EC2_NVMe_Instance_Storage_*-ns-1` was used, but that doesn't match anymore.

Comment: Interesting. I see two links for each disk. One with -ns-1 at the end and one without. Tried on im4gn and d3 instances today.